# spring boot unauthorized on permit all requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security

So I have a very common problem but, all answers didn't work so I hope this will help me...
I am using spring boot and want to permit all request without authentication, but I want to keep the csrf token and the jsession.

The problem is when I use this:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
```

It just says unauthorized...
@jaop answer works for get, but for post it still says unothorized

Please Help,
Thanks

Comment: Can you add log of application?

Comment: @jaop thanks for the answer it works for the get request but not for post, if you answer how also to do with post you get the answer !

Comment: Hi Iau. The question is what is the point to enable CSRF on public resources? CSRF token protects users of your application from unintentional sending a request that can cause unwanted implications of calling protected API winthin user session. This is why CSRF protection is enabled only on HTTP verbs that are designeted for modifying state and not on GET, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS.
Check this reference for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
http.httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

Basically i think you should disable basic authentication =)

Let me know if it works